# Correct way to run two WSGI / Django instances from Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualhost, wsgi

I have an application written in Python Django.

I would like to have two instances of this running - a production version, plus a test version, where I can push new features to and let users test them. I would like the urls to be:

```
top.level.domain/production/url-to-specific-page/
```

and

```
top.levl.domain/test/url-to-specific-page/
```

My sysadmins have set me up with an Apache file in conf.d that I can edit for virtualhosts. I tried adding two script aliases in here, but they end up pointing to whatever version of the application is accessed first.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.cat
    ServerAlias  list-of-server-names
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myserver.cat
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/myserver_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/myserver.cat_access.log common


    AccessFileName .htaccess
    <Directory /var/www/html/myserver.cat>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/myserver.cat/data>
            AllowOverride All
            Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests   Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>


    Alias /static /var/www/html/myserver/myapplication/webform/db_sync/static
    WSGIScriptAlias /sampleimport /var/www/html/myserver/myapplication/webform/webform/wsgi.py
    WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/html/myserver/test/myapplication/webform/webform/wsgi_test.py
</virtualhost>
```

wsgi.py is as follows

```
import sys 
code_directory = 'directory/where/django/prod/code/lives'
sys.path.append(code_directory)

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webform.settings_prod")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

wsgi_test.py is the same, except for the code_directory variable, and the settings file.

When I run this set up, the different urls seem to point to the same database depending on which of test / production is accessed first. I assume the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is getting set then is not getting changed when the other url is accessed.

What is the correct way to set up two instances like this?

Comment: have you tried doing it this way ...
top.level.domain/url...
test.top.level.domain/url...

Comment: No, is there any reason that would be preferable? I have access to the config file, so I can alter that all I want, but I would need to get sysadmins to set up an alternative top level domain.

Comment: I do it that way on my personal hosted site.  It works well for me.